# Why doesn't TypeScript give me a compile time error when running inexistent method on imported object?

Tags: typescript

[Here is the repo for this question](https://github.com/evian-pring/ts1) and if you want you can clone that repo, compile using TypeScript, and run it in node to see that there is a runtime error, but no compile time error.

To cut to the chase: why do I not get a compile time error by TypeScript in file1 when I try to run a method of an object imported from another module file2, given that the object has no methods?

This is the code, basically:

To set up the project:

```
mkdir test
cd test
npm init --yes
yarn add typescript
touch tsconfig.json
touch index.ts
touch jsModule.js
```

Here is `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]

}
```

Here are the two files I created:

```
// jsModule.js

export const MyModuleObject = {};

// index.ts
import { MyModuleObject } from './jsModule';
console.log(MyModuleObject.method());
```

Problem: Typescript does not say anything about me calling `MyModuleObject.method()`

Comment: I am not sure but `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` option might be issue as it effects type checking. You might want to take a look at the [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26866/commits/aaa723e2d2ee393331ac9d8eba29d66b80f415fe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576203/do-i-ever-need-explicit-allowsyntheticdefaultimports-if-esmoduleinterop-is-true).

Comment: why is `jsModule` a javascript file? Can you convert `jsModule.js` to typescript?

Comment: This question came up when I was trying to understand the typescript `declare` keyword. I wanted to have a TS file that imports an untyped module (as I'm doing in this example), and I expected TS to show me errors (which I'm not seeing and is the reason for this question). I would then remedy those errors by using the `declare` keyword to declare whatever is being exported from the untyped JS file. Not sure if my line of reasoning is correct, but this was my intention to understand `declare`.

Comment: By default the compiler will not typecheck js files. You can enable it with the `checkJs` in combination with `allowJs` compiler options https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files

Comment: Please see this too, my next question, about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869440/what-is-the-simplest-possible-example-of-where-declare-keyword-is-useful-in-ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"noImplicitAny": false` in `tsconfig.json` causes your problem.

It simply means "allow implicit any". Since TS knows nothing about what is exported from `jsModule.js`, you effectively allow TS to assign `any` as the type of that module. `MyModuleObject.method()` becomes `any.any()`, which is fine.

Set `"noImplicitAny": true`, then TS will complain.

Comment: But `MyModuleObject` type is inferred from `{}`.

Comment: That's basically an any.

Comment: No it's not: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20MyModuleObject%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(MyModuleObject.method())%3B

Comment: @shusson you're right. I redraw my statement. Type wasn't inferred from `{}` in the .js file.