# What is the simplest possible example of where `declare` keyword is useful in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've read docs (ie, [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html)) and a few blog posts about `declare` keyword in TypeScript and I still don't understand it. What I would like is a clear example of its most simple usage.

Here is the line of reasoning I initially came up with to come up with this simplest example (which is likely incorrect):

Have a `.js` file export something (untyped because this is plain JS).

Have a `.ts` file import whatever the `.js` file exported.

What needs to be exported and imported (an object? a function?) for me to see TS show an error that could be fixed by using `declare`?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13348 i guess this is related

Comment: `noImplicitAny: true` to make ts complain, then fix the error by `declare`

Comment: The "docs" are actually at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html, and there's a specific section about declaration files: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html. Much love to basarat for putting together the Deep Dive; it is very helpful, but sometimes going to the source is a good idea.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't see the `declare` keyword used in the deep dive doc. Did I miss something?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript

Comment: @cham That was the point of the comment; `declare` was not mentioned in basarat's book at that time (the comment is over a year old). But it was mentioned in the documentation on TypeScript's own site. My suggestion is to go to the source. In this case, `declare` is specifically mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Murat Karagöz answer above pointed in the right direction, and this answer will provide actual code with the minimal example of where we would use `declare`.

[Here](https://github.com/evian-pring/npmModule) is a very simple npm module: just one `index.js` file that exports an object with one method on it. There are no type declarations here because it's just JS.

```
const item = {
    price: 5,
    name: 'item1',
};

export const MyModuleObject = { method: () => item };
```

[Here](https://github.com/evian-pring/ts) is a very simple TypeScript npm project, with one dependency: the JS project linked above. The latter is therefore an imported npm module with no typings. Here is the index.ts file in the TS project:

```
/// <reference path="index.d.ts"/>

import { MyModuleObject } from 'npmModule';

import { LocalModuleObject } from './module';

// Without the "reference path" line, TS complains in line 3 that it could not find a declaration file for 'npmModule'.
// In this case, the import has type any, so TS does not complain about the call below to an inexistent method.
// When we uncomment line 1, we get a TS error on line 8: property 'test' does not exist on type { method: ... }
MyModuleObject.test();


// TS complains that test does not exist on type { method: ... }
// Here we did not need to have a `declare` statement in a type definitions file for TS to know this because here TS is
// using contextual typing:
LocalModuleObject.test();
```

Below is the code for `index.d.ts`:

```
declare module "npmModule" {
    export const Item: {
        price: number,
        name: string
    }

    export const MyModuleObject: {
        method: () => Item
    }
}
```

And the code for `./module`:

```
export const LocalModuleObject = { method: () => 10 };
```

**How is this an example of why declare is used**
- I put this in the comments of `index.ts`, but let me explain it in more words. `index.ts` is importing an object from an external module (one that is in `node_modules`), and another object from a local module (`./module.js`). Both modules are exporting an object with one method called `method` on it. In `index.ts` I am calling an inexistent method `test` on each of these objects.

TS uses contextual typing on the import of the local module, so it knows that `test` doesn't exist on the object. This does not happen on the import of the object in the external module: this import is imported with type `any`. Therefore, TS does not complain about the call to the inexistent method `test`. It does, however, complain that there are no typings for the external module, so this is a hint that implicit `any` is being used.

We can remedy this latter complaint by defining an `index.d.ts` that provides typings for the external library. This is where `declare module` is used: it declares what it is that the module `npmModule` exports; `npmModule` is the external import. In `index.ts` we must add the line `/// <reference path="index.d.ts"/>` so TS knows where to look for types.

Answer (score 6):

Your example is correct. For example you are using a node module which is written in plain javascript (no typings available), so the tscompiler will notice that (since it searches for the typings which are usually in the node module or an extra `@typings/package`).

You can however provide those typings yourself by telling the tscompiler in the `tsconfig.json` to look at file `xyz.d.ts` for the typings e.g.

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The `index.d.ts` is where all your custom typings are gathered which can look like this

```
index.d.ts
/// <reference path="custom-typings.d.ts" />
```

and the `custom-typings.d.ts` has the actual typings in it. This is where the `declare` keyword comes into play

```
custom-typings.d.ts
declare module "the-untyped-node-module-name" {
    export default class TheNodeModuleClass { 
        static showNotification(string: any): void;
    }
}
```

Now the Typescript Compiler knows there is a `TheNodeModuleClass` in `the-untyped-node-module-name` which has the static function `showNotification`.

For more info [See Typscript Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import).

---

This is one use case for the keyword `declare`. There are of course more of it like `declare var`, `declare function`, `declare class` and so on.

Comment: Here is a simple gist: https://gist.github.com/evian-pring/ce3aa59c01f6fb2b1cec806519fc8f89

Can I suppose that `myModule.js` is the equivalent of a node module written in plain JS that I would add to my project through node_modules? If TypeScript can infer types like that, can you give an example of where it can't infer and I would need to necessarily use `declare`?

Comment: @evianpring That one is called [Contextual Typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) and works that way. However it does not work for external imports from node_modules.