# TSLint `import-name` complains about import React from 'react' and turns it lowercase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, tslint

I'm currently using React with TypeScript and TSLint and up until now I was importing React as:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

I'd like  to switch that to:

```
import React from 'react';
```

So that I don't need an additional line and `const` declaration to destructure hooks like `useCallback`, `useEffect` or `useRef`:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
```

But I get the following error from TSLint:

> Misnamed import. Import should be named 'react' but found 'React' (`import-name`) `tslint(1)`

When running with `fix: true`, that will automatically be converted to:

```
import react from 'react';
```

The error will go away, but I'd like to keep it as `React`.

I'm using TypeScript `3.5.1` and TSLint `5.17.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make that error go away you need to add this `rule` into `tslint.json`:

```
"import-name": [true, { "react": "React" }],
```

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib):

> Since version `2.0.9` it is possible to configure this rule with a list of exceptions.
>
> For example, to allow underscore to be imported as `_`, add this configuration:
>
> ```
>  'import-name': [ true, { 'underscore': '_' }]
> ```

Then, in `tsconfig.json` you need to add:

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

While `"esModuleInterop": true` should set `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` automatically (so there's no need to define both), there was an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26866/commits/aaa723e2d2ee393331ac9d8eba29d66b80f415fe) with that and some tools might be checking the value of those flags, so you might need to set both if using an pre-fix TypeScript version.

For more on that, see [Do I ever need explicit allowSyntheticDefaultImports if esModuleInterop is true configuring TypeScript transpilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576203/do-i-ever-need-explicit-allowsyntheticdefaultimports-if-esmoduleinterop-is-true).

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> **`--allowSyntheticDefaultImports`**: Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking.
>
> **`--esModuleInterop`**: Emit `__importStar` and `__importDefault` helpers for runtime babel ecosystem compatibility and enable `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for typesystem compatibility.

Also, `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` was added in TypeScript `1.8` while `esModuleInterop` was added in TypeScript `2.7`, so depending on the version you are using you would have to stick to `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`. For more on that, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-7/

If you don't set them, you will get the following error:

> Module '".../node_modules/@types/react/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

If you are still getting errors when setting one or the two of them to `true`, it might be worth taking a look at: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27329.